# Auto import in entire project

Tags: scala

I got a few classes and functions that are used almost in every file in my project,
so that every file starts with `import com.organization.myapp.MyObject._`

Is it possible to have this import to happen automatically in the entire project?
(something like `Predef` but only in my project)

I tried using `package object` but from what I gather, it will only work for the level it was defined at, i.e.:
if I got the packages:

```
- com.organization.myapp.package1
- com.organization.myapp.package2
- com.organization.myapp.package3
```

defining

```
package com.organization
package object myapp {...}
```

won't be auto imported in `package1`, `package2` and `package3`

Comment: If anything, I'd recommend doing the opposite.  Blindly importing many libraries can lead to not realizing where implicit conversions are coming from, which is problematic to say the least.  If anything, you might want to consider importing on a smaller scale, within individual objects and the like.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `com.organization.myapp` package object, i.e.:

```
// This file is in the com/organization/myapp folder
package com.organization

package object myapp {
    // Definitions such as
    val MyConstant = "foo"
}
```

The definitions will be in scope for files in the `com.organization.myapp` package.

If you want these definitions to also be in scope from a file in the `com.organization.myapp.package1` package, all you have to do is slightly alter the way you declare that file's package:

```
// This file is in the com/organization/myapp/package1 folder
package com.organization.myapp
package package1

class MyClass {
    val foo = MyConstant // in scope
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. There is no way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported in Scala.

If you really want it, you can 'hack' it if your IDE supports creating templates then you can define a new-file template that includes the import you need.

Comment: Nice idea, but would be difficult to be used in a team.

Comment: @lev - Again, depends on the IDE. For example in IntelliJ you can share the setting with the team.